# how to change log levels of 3rd party library in java

Tags: java, spring, logging, apache-zookeeper, spring-kafka

The console logs is cluttered with logs from 3rd part libraries. For example my project uses kafka and zooker keeper client libraries because of this there are too many logs from them

1. 2018-05-08 10:30:38.250  INFO 2968 --- [0:0:0:0:1:2181)]
   org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn          : Opening socket connection
   to server 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:2181. Will not attempt to
   authenticate using SASL (unknown error)
2. 2018-05-08 10:30:38.309  INFO 2968 --- [           main]
       o.a.k.clients.producer.ProducerConfig    : ProducerConfig values:

   there is a log4j2.xml file in my project. Changing root log level in xml file only changes log level of the custom logs generated by my project.
   Is there a way to stop or changes logs of these libraries

Comment: What logging API are the 3rd party libraries using? Do the log entries go into your log file? If so, and since you use Log4j2, just configure the log level for the libraries to `WARN` level, so `INFO` log entries aren't written to the file. If you don't know how to do that, now would be a great time to read the Log4j2 documentation to learn how it works.

Comment: all the 3rd party lib were using using logback. I was editing the wrong log configuration. thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Switch to Logback and change the logging level for flooding logger. Usually, it names after its class reference.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
 <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <encoder>
        <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
 </appender>
 <logger name="flooding logger" level="ERROR" additivity="false">
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT"/>
 </logger>
 <root level="INFO">
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT"/>
 </root>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Thanks. I thought they they were using log4j. Wasted so many days configuring wrong xml file.