# Disable PDFBox logging with Springboot org.apache.commons.logging

Tags: java, spring-boot, logging, pdfbox

I can't find a way to stop warnings from PDFBox I am using in a psring boot application. For example:

```
2019-10-01 16:53:51.021  WARN 24564 --- [nio-8443-exec-2] o.a.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDType0Font      : No Unicode mapping for CID+4 (4) in font Calibri-Bold

2019-10-01 16:53:51.022  WARN 24564 --- [nio-8443-exec-2] o.a.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDCIDFontType2   : Failed to find a character mapping for 4 in Calibri-Bold

2019-10-01 16:53:51.022  WARN 24564 --- [nio-8443-exec-2] o.a.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDCIDFontType2   : Failed to find a character mapping for 4 in Calibri-Bold
```

I have tried:
In Application file:

```
static {
  System.setProperty("org.apache.commons.logging.Log", "org.apache.commons.logging.impl.NoOpLog");
  java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("org.apache.pdfbox").setLevel(java.util.logging.Level.OFF);

  String[] loggers = {
    "org.apache.pdfbox.util.PDFStreamEngine",
    "org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDSimpleFont",
    "org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDFont",
    "org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.FontManager",
    "org.apache.pdfbox.pdfparser.PDFObjectStreamParser",
    "o.a.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDCIDFontType2",
    "org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDCIDFontType2",
    "o.a.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDType0Font",
    "org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDType0Font",
    "org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDType1Font"
  };
  for (String logger: loggers) {
    org.apache.log4j.Logger logpdfengine = org.apache.log4j.Logger
      .getLogger(logger);
    logpdfengine.setLevel(org.apache.log4j.Level.OFF);
  }

}
```

As parameter when running jar:

```
-Dorg.apache.commons.logging.Log=org.apache.commons.logging.impl.NoOpLog
-Dorg.slf4j.simpleLogger.defaultLogLevel=off
```

Within the PDFBox code, the log is set up using:

```
(import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;)

private static final Log LOG = LogFactory.getLog(PDCIDFontType0.class);

LOG.warn("Found PFB but expected embedded CFF font " + fd.getFontName());
```

I've spent a long time trying a lot of things and trolled through the answers for similar questions in SO but not got anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I have been using in the "old" log4j `log4j.properties` file (you should migrate to log4j2):

```
log4j.logger.org.springframework=WARN
log4j.logger.org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDCIDFontType2=FATAL
```

In the "new" `log4j2.xml` I have this (the appenders are named `STDOUT` and `A1`):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html 
     https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html
-->
<Configuration>
    <Appenders>
        ....
        ....
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Logger name="org.springframework" level="warn" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="STDOUT"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="A1"/>
        </Logger>
        <Logger name="org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDCIDFontType2" level="fatal" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="STDOUT"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="A1"/>
        </Logger>
        <Root level="info">
            <AppenderRef ref="STDOUT"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="A1"/>
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

Comment: Hi Tilman, I've added the properties file to the resources folder but the warnings are still coming.  Is there a setting I need to put (eg in application.properties) to tell spring boot to refer to the file?

Comment: Also, I have just used the default settings for logging in Spring Boot - I have not included any logging specific dependencies and have no logging setting in my properties file.

Comment: If you didn't use a properties file before, then I wonder if log4j was involved in your logging at all. (However I don't use Spring Boot myself, I only use it with Spring Framework). This website mentions to exclude logback: https://www.mkyong.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-log4j-2-example/

Comment: This website explains how to do what you want to do (exclude pdfbox) with the standard logging of spring boot (logback): https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-logging

Comment: This seemed to work, adding in the flooding logger to the logback file.  Thanks for you help Tilman.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50226224/how-to-change-log-levels-of-3rd-party-library-in-java

Answer (score 1):

This is the configuration file I ended up using.  I didn't include any logging releated dependencies or add any exclusions to pdfbox dependency, just added this file to the folder containing the application.properties file.

Filename is logback-spring.xml

The flooding logger was copied from [how to change log levels of 3rd party library in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50226224/how-to-change-log-levels-of-3rd-party-library-in-java)

```
<property name="LOGS" value="./logs" />

<appender name="Console"
    class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout">
        <Pattern>
            %black(%d{ISO8601}) %highlight(%-5level) [%blue(%t)] %yellow(%C{1.}): %msg%n%throwable
        </Pattern>
    </layout>
</appender>

<appender name="RollingFile"
    class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <file>${LOGS}/spring-boot-logger.log</file>
    <encoder
        class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
        <Pattern>%d %p %C{1.} [%t] %m%n</Pattern>
    </encoder>

    <rollingPolicy
        class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
        <!-- rollover daily and when the file reaches 10 MegaBytes -->
        <fileNamePattern>${LOGS}/archived/spring-boot-logger-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log
        </fileNamePattern>
        <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy
            class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
            <maxFileSize>10MB</maxFileSize>
        </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
    </rollingPolicy>
</appender>

<!-- LOG everything at INFO level -->
<root level="info">
    <appender-ref ref="RollingFile" />
    <appender-ref ref="Console" />
</root>

<!-- LOG "com.baeldung*" at TRACE level -->
<logger name="org.apache" level="ERROR" additivity="false">
    <appender-ref ref="RollingFile" />
    <appender-ref ref="Console" />
</logger>

<logger name="flooding logger" level="ERROR" additivity="false">
  <appender-ref ref="Console"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this also should work for **log4j2.** I use this simple way of disabling logs from specific libraries in **SpringBoot** applications. You need just add it into the log4j2.xml file.

```
<Loggers>  
    <Root>
        ****** here is some AppenderRef *******
    </Root>      
    <Logger name="o.a.pdfbox" level="off"/>
    or 
    <Logger name="org.apache.pdfbox" level="off"/> 

</Loggers>
```